# .htaccess not working on WAMP

Tags: .htaccess, wampserver

I have installed WAMP on Windows. I found .htaccess files are not working here. Is there any way to work with .htaccess?

Comment: How do you know if it's not working? Or you meant rewriting not working? Or? What exactly is not working?

Comment: when i try to put .htaccess file (to use mode rewrite) ,it showing page not found error

Comment: could you post the content of .htaccess and how you are accessing your page?

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

Comment: I come to know it need to modify "AccessFileName .htaccess"  to "AccessFileName htaccess.txt" and changed this file name on server.But still not get any result.

Answer (score 24):

Click on Wamp icon and open Apache/httpd.conf and search "rewrite_module". Remove # as below and save it

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after that restart all service.

Answer (score 20):

1) Left click WAMP icon

2) Apache

3) Apache Modules

4) Left click **rewrite_module**

Comment: Makes me feel silly to have looked this up (seems so obvious now). Thanks anyway!

Comment: hey I also followed @andy steps. But by default rewrite_module is working. (green right mark is there before file name). In my case I want to remove .php extensions from files when it appear in url box. I'm using following code 
`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]`
I think my .httaccess is not working...  Because still showing .php extension end of the url.

Comment: This CAN be a bugger to get working, there are many many many many problems ahead of you :] Keep digigng.

Answer (score 1):

Open Apache/conf/httpd.conf and search "rewrite_module".

Remove # as below

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
as 
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Then Save it and restart your server. It will work.

Comment: Thanks Tamilselvan, In my wampp2.2 this feature is disabled. According your help my problem is solved after 2 hour. Really thanks.