# Cant redirect my URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using WAMP and my url is `localhost/hotel/hotels.php?id=21`
Using rewrite rule as follow,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule hotels/id/(.*)/ hotels.php?id=$1
RewriteRule hotels/id/(.*) hotels.php?id=$1
```

But nothing happens..

My mod_rewrite is on and also changes done in `httpd.conf` file.

Please give me a suggestion to handle the issue?

Comment: What is supposed to happen with `hotels.php?id=21`? I mean, something should happen with `hotels/id/21`, but it won't change a thing for `hotels.php?id=21`!

Comment: yes.. i want it to change to hotels/id/21 but nothing changed. the url remains same even after doing everything.

Comment: Well you have to go to `localhost/hotel/hotels/id/21`, a rewrite rule isn't a redirection!

Comment: ohh thank you.. How to make redirection then. can you please help me on this?

Comment: You should check out the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) about redirections

Comment: can you please giv me a solution here?? i will be thankful for you

Answer (score 1):

You must use [flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for your RewriteRule. You can change it as follow

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^hotels/id/([\d]+)/?$ hotels.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can call your pages from

> localhost/hotel/hotels/id/12

If your .htaccess file is located in **localhost/hotel** .

Comment: how to redirect the original page to the rewritten page.. ?

Comment: If http://localhost/hotel/hotels.php?id=21 works, you can use http://localhost/hotel/hotels/id/21  . If your .htaccess file is located on hotel folder. Please check .htaccess working with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321990/htaccess-not-working-on-wamp