# remove the index.php WAMP

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, wamp

I have a site and it works to type "www.mysite.com/folder/" *(if i have a index file in that folder).*

It also works to type "www.mysite.com/folder/index.php"

All fine and good, but I want it so if you type /index.php it will remove the index.php on the end also if I use a form and post to index.php I don't want that to show in the url.

I have looked around and seen every solution say .htaccess rewrite, but It don't seem to be working / or its just not the same thing that I want?

or do I need to use javascript and update the address bar?

*(I'm using WAMP)*

**EDIT:**

Things I've have tried:

## 1

*httpd.conf*

```
AllowOverride All
```

## 2

I have enabled:
*Apache modules> rewrite_module*

## 3

I have created a .htaccess placed in my *wamp/www folder*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

## 4

*wamp/apps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php*
added

```
$cfg['index_page'] = '';
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
This look like it  works, but it messes up my POST to index.php so it breaks my login *(It don't start the session)*.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: for index.php, you don't need ANYTHING fancy. just `DirectoryIndex index.php`. If you want ALL php scripts to be seen as `/path/to/script` instead of `/path/to/script.php`, then you will need some mod_rewrite magic.

Comment: What **possible effect** did you think that amending `wamp/apps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` would have on **anything** other than `phpMyAdmin` You do realise that phpMyAdmin is just a took that helps you fiddle with a `MYSQL` database _i hope_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't think I't but I just added it because I had seen it as a suggesting somewhere.

Comment: **Beware** There is lots of advice out there, most of it is written by morons, specially in the WAMPServer area

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: @RiggsFolly If the answer for the duplicate question does not resolve the OP's problem, is it really a duplicate question? I request re-opening (or perhaps helping the OP solve his problem).

Answer (score 1):

An `.htaccess` file is definitely the correct solution. If it isn't working, try one of these possible answer:

[.htaccess not working on localhost with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp)

[How to use .htaccess in WAMP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server)

[.htaccess not working on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321990/htaccess-not-working-on-wamp)

---

Update: Re-reading your question, [you might be using an older htaccess script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365161/1447509) (for PHP < 5.2.6 version). I'm not sure if the script will work in current versions. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

*The ? after index.php in final line is the difference*

If above doesn't help, what version of PHP does the PHP command `phpinfo()` report?

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
    die();
```

Comment: ok, good I at least know that its .htaccess thats the solution to my problem, but I have already looked at those solutions^ and tried the stuff but noting changes on the server still /index.php shows if i type it, (I have restarted wamp services)

Comment: That did not work either, and php info: PHP Version 5.5.12

Comment: One more point - your problem is likely due to WAMP issue rather than htaccess issue. How important is it to you to resolve this in the WAMP environment? *If you are working in a WAMP dev environment now but will later upload to production environment (perhaps a shared hosting LAMP config) then you can rest assured that the `htaccess` code you posted above will work there.*

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true it's not that important right now while using WAMP,  just thought I't would be nice and easy.

Comment: Yeah, so did I. Sometimes those xampp/wamp environs have their peculiarities. I was hoping Rory would help out as he could probably put his finger right on the problem with a bit of head-scratching, but he's pretty busy.

Comment: If you can do it on Apache with a rewrite you can do it on a windows version of Apache

Comment: @PatrikFröhler Well, Rory confirms that it will definitely work, and he's an authority on WAMP / Apache / PHP. If it's worth the fuss, you can dig into it and I'm sure you'll resolve the matter. However, you won't have the problem when you move to your production server. *Best wishes with your project*

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciates it ,  I updated my post with something that I got to almost work, it does remove the index.php but when I use it I cant POST to index.php anymore.